# Why are the textures on imported objects not displaying correctly in my scene?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, import, versions

I have a small scene with an imported CAD model in Blender 2.9. I have textured a vastly similar model before and imported the textures from the old project (Blender Version 2.82) into the new one.

The preview in the material tab displays the texture correctly (A).
When I apply the material to any imported object in my scene, I only get a solid color material without texture. This applies to the viewport as well as a rendered image (1).
When I copy the object the material was originally applied to from the old project file, it is displaying correctly in my current scene (2).
When I create a new mesh and apply the texture on it, it is also displaying correctly (3).
[image: (A)]

What could be the reason for the tiled texture is not displaying on the imported objects?
You can download the full project file and take a look yourself.
https://filebin.net/1jzdwh6t52jtfioi/Texture_issue_scene.blend?t=pm3p6t1q

Comment: I didn't check your file, but isn't that your CAD model is missing a UV map?

Comment: I tried to work with UVs and I unwrapped the object in question. It didn't solve the issue and the old object wasn't unwrapped either, yet it still seems to be working.

Comment: Please for a next time share just simplified blend file, like only object 123 seems to be enough to see issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object 1 doesn't have an UV map, object 2 have.
When I *Unwrap* object one, like Cube projection or if you go to top view and *Unwrap from View*, it works for me.

[image]

Comment: Well, that makes me look like an idiot :)
Apparently, when I tried unwrapping last time, I did something wrong. After reading your comment I tried it again with cube projection, now it works. Classic issue, classic solution. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: No problem. We all have those ... :) We use to say "The greatest darkness is under the candlestick".